# Use jQuery to animate height of different dynamic height divs simultaneously

Tags: jquery, each

I have 6 different divs each with a different height. Each div contains dynamic content so the height of each div is different. The initial height of each div is set to 32px using CSS.

Each div contains a h3 tag. Clicking on any h3 tag should animate all divs to their own heights. Clicking again should return all divs back to a height of 32px.

I almost have it. At the moment the divs expand to the height of the first div instead of their own heights.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$('.vintage-icons h3').on('click touch',function(){

            $('.vintage-icons h3').each(function(){
            var autoheight = $('.vintage-icons h3').parent().get(0).scrollHeight;
            console.log(autoheight);
            if(!$(this).is(".open")) {
                $('.vintage-icons h3').parent().animate({'height':autoheight},750);
                $(this).addClass('open');
            }else if($(this).is(".open")) {
                $('.vintage-icons h3').parent().animate({'height':'32px'},750);
                $(this).removeClass('open');
            }
            return false;
            });
        });

<div class="vintage-icons">
    <div>
        <h3 class="open"><a href="#">TITLE1</a></h3>
        <p>Dynamic content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">TITLE2</a></h3>
        <p>Dynamic content 2 Dynamic content 2 Dynamic content 2 Dynamic content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">TITLE3</a></h3>
        <p>Dynamic content 3 Dynamic content 3 Dynamic content 3</p>
    </div>
</div>

.vintage-icons div{
    height:32px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: and css as well

Comment: posted html & css

Comment: `var autoheight = $(this).parent().get(0).scrollHeight;` and then `$(this).parent().animate({'height':autoheight},750);` --> https://jsfiddle.net/z91g706o/

Comment: @Amani Thanks but your jsfiddle does not open/close all divs simultaneously

Comment: @RichardTinkler that's because you've hardcoded the 'open' class into one of the HTML elements already. See my snippet below for the working version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to this line: `var autoheight = $(this).parent().get(0).scrollHeight;`

Don't return false.

Then it will work.

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.vintage-icons h3').on('click touch',function(){

            $(".vintage-icons h3").each(function(){
             var autoheight = $(this).parent().get(0).scrollHeight;
             if(!$(this).is(".open")) {
                 $(this).parent().animate({'height':autoheight},750);
                 $(this).addClass('open');
             }else if($(this).is(".open")) {
                 $(this).parent().animate({'height':'32px'},750);
                 $(this).removeClass('open');
             }
            });
        });
 });
</script>
<style>
 .vintage-icons div{
     height:32px;
     overflow:hidden;
     width: 60px;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="vintage-icons">
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">TITLE1</a></h3>
        <p>Dynamic content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">TITLE2</a></h3>
        <p>Dynamic content 2 Dynamic content 2 Dynamic content 2 Dynamic content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h3><a href="#">TITLE3</a></h3>
        <p>Dynamic content 3 Dynamic content 3 Dynamic content 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

`var autoheight = $('.vintage-icons h3').parent().get(0).scrollHeight;`

This gets the value for the first `h3`. Then, in `each` of the following `h3` you set to the same `autoheight`. You probably could use this instead:

`var autoheight = $(this).parent().get(0).scrollHeight;`

You can use `$(this)` in this case since you are already inside `each` of the `h3` elements.

Comment: Changing from '.vintage-icons h3' to 'this' doesn't make any difference. All divs still expand to height of first div.